# Is [舐]{な}める a stative verb?

Tags: words

I was looking up the definition for [舐]{な}める and "underestimate" was one of them. However, "underestimate" can be both stative or dynamic, so I looked up the Japanese definition and got this:

> 人を馬鹿にして無礼な態度をとる。あなどる。

While とる is certainly a dynamic verb, I am not quite certain if [侮]{あなど}る is one as well. Looking up the Japanese definition for 侮る leads me to an endless cycle of the following words.

- 見くびる
- [軽蔑]{けいべつ}する
- [見]{み}[下]{くだ}す
- [見]{み}[下]{お}ろす
- 見なす
- 甘く見る
- ばかにする

While the Japanese definitions of 軽蔑する and 見なす make them seem dynamic, example sentences make them seem stative.

> 私達は、その計画を価値あるものと見なす。
>
> We think of the plan as of value.
>
> ([on jisho.org](http://classic.jisho.org/sentences?jap=%E8%A6%8B%E3%81%AA%E3%81%99))

and

> 彼は社会的地位の低い人を軽蔑する。
>
> He despises people of a lower social class.
>
> ([on jisho.org](http://classic.jisho.org/sentences?jap=%E8%BB%BD%E8%94%91%E3%81%99%E3%82%8B))

This is further complicated by how I am not sure of what 馬鹿にする means anymore. At first I thought it merely meant "to make fun of someone" but on further inspection, にする can mean "to feel A about B" and makes expressions such as 大切にする stative. For example:

> 一郎は利益よりも友情を大切にする

[jisho.org](http://classic.jisho.org/sentences?jap=%E5%A4%A7%E5%88%87%E3%81%ABsuru) has got this translation:

> Ichiro puts friendship above profit.

Now I wonder if 馬鹿にする can mean to merely regard someone as stupid and not that you actively go to make fun of them.

Comment: Might depend upon the defintion of `stative verb`. How about this classification: [金田一の日本語動詞分類 1](http://amigo.hum.fukuoka-u.ac.jp/koga/index.php?blog/2009_11_27) and
[金田一の日本語動詞分類 2](http://amigo.hum.fukuoka-u.ac.jp/koga/index.php?blog/2010_04_05)?

Comment: I think all dynamic verbs can be used in this way. For example: 日本語を話す。酒を飲む。But when you put the verb in the past form, it becomes obvious that they are not stative verbs. For example 日本語を話した・酒を飲んだ・ずいぶん舐められたもんだ ・

Comment: @"Yang Muye" As far I understand it (see links above), there's also a difference if one thinks about actions/states currently happening. You can't say うちの子は**今**公園で遊ぶ (dynamic), but you can say 子供たちは**今**公園にいる (static).

Comment: Well, "stative verb" as defined by wikipedia is "one that describes a state of being," which is what I will use. The main thing that confuses me on verbs such as 舐める and 侮る is whether they refer to "having the opinion that someone is inferior" or "making the judgment that someone is inferior." The former would be stative while the latter would be dynamic.

Comment: I personnally think they are pretty much the same thing. The difference is not in meaning, but in grammar. In English you do not say _be having_ in the stative sense, but in Japanese, you normally say 持っている, and only occationally say 持つ for some reason. 持つ normally means very different from _have_. However when 取る is used instead of 持つ in the collocation 態度をとる, both 取る and 取っている are possible though not exactly the same. とる are often more abstract than とっている. Similarly, you say 好意を持つ, too. Verbs are hard. Over years, I have never found it possible to fit a verb into the 金田一's four categories.

Comment: Sometimes I feel that the dictionary form of a Japanese verb can take any any tense it wants rather than just indicating future tense and habitual actions. For example, in a light novel I was reading I came upon the sentence 俺の知る波島出海ちゃんその人のものだと信じられた, which is blatantly wrong under our current definition of the dictionary form of a Japanese verb. However, sentences that "misuse" the dictionary form of a Japanese verb are so numerous in fiction that I cannot help but suspect that there is more to unmodified Japanese verbs than just future tense and habitual actions.

Comment: That's an interesting sentence. At least as far as 知る is concerned, it seems to me that the plain/dictionary form is a lot more common when used attributively, ie. 俺の知る波島出海ちゃん but 俺は波島出海ちゃんを知っている

Comment: @Joe I can't figure out what you think is strange about 知る in that example.  Maybe you could ask it as a separate question.

Comment: 知る is undoubtedly a dynamic verb. It does not mean "to know" which is meant by 知っている but rather "to learn" or "to gain new information." 彼が死んだと知った does not mean "I knew that he died" but rather "I learned that he died." There's also how it's present tense rather than past tense to fit the rest of the sentence.

Answer (score 2):

Aspects in Japanese are complicated. I think there are some concepts at play here which haven't been mentioned. (The below grammaticality assessments are mine.)

1. The tendency to (ability to) use dictionary forms for 1st person, where ている/でいる must be used for 3rd person for some thought/speech verbs, e.g. 私は思う but 彼は思っている. I think the same thing is going on for みなす here.

   - 私達は、その計画を価値あるものと見なす。
   - 私達は、その計画を価値あるものと見なしている。
   - ?? 彼は、その計画を価値あるものと見なす。
   - 彼は、その計画を価値あるものと見なしている。

     2. The habitual use of the dictionary form. Here it works because 会的地位の低い人 is plural and can be viewed as a stream of people which "he" habitually looks down upon.
   - 彼は社会的地位の低い人を軽蔑する。
   - 彼は社会的地位の低い人を軽蔑している。
   - ?? 彼は母を軽蔑する。
   - 彼は母を軽蔑している。

Comment: Well, I think I've come up with a sort of way to test if a verb is stative. In an earlier question, someone told me to use もう to test if a verb is resultive or progressive, and I realized I could also use that to differentiate stative and dynamic. For example, in sentences like もう彼を見下さない and　もう彼を侮らない I feel like they are stative similar to sentences like もう彼が敵だと思わない.

Comment: @joe, sorry, what is the test? You use もう with the simple negative form and then...?

Comment: @Joe How would もう遊ばない, もう(Xと[は])話さない, もう笑わない, もう届かない feel to you? These are usually not classified as stative, but personally, I can't see much of a difference (?)

Comment: @blutorange Your examples describe habitual action, as in you will never do X action again in the future. When もう is used with a stative verb, it describes a situation in the present. For example, もういない means "isn't here anymore" and もう敵だと思わない means "no longer think (hold the opinion) that he is an enemy." However, もう遊ばない would mean "won't play" and もう笑わない means "won't laugh anymore."

Answer (score 2):

## Meaning-wise

Considering only what a verb means to determine whether it is stative can be somewhat subjective. If we go purely by the semantics, we find as you mentioned the following explanation for the relevant sense:

> 馬鹿にする。甘くみる。みくびる。あなどる。

As this suggests, `underestimate` does not convey the nuance of the verb very well. Think of it like this:

> 彼をなめる (*dynamic*-like): to view/take him lightly, to treat him like a fool, to disparage him, to make light of him, to look down on him
>
> ＡはＢをなめている (*stative*-like): A is taking B lightly, A underestimates be

And its more dynamic nature becomes easier to see. In the 〜ている form, it is more stative-like. The [zokugo](http://zokugo-dict.com/21na/nameru.htm) dictionary contains the following explanation

> なめるとは相手やある物事を馬鹿にしたり、みくびったり、軽んじる、蔑むといった**行為**で、戦国時代には既にこうした意味で使われている。

Here we see that the verb usually involves people doing something that could be regarded as them taking something lightly. This makes sense if we consider this an extended meaning of `to lick`.

Now if we use it in an actual sentences such as

> 敗戦国民として、われわれは彼らに嘗められているんです

The plain form is not used here as a predicate for a sentence expressing a current action. This is as close to a state as you can get, but (a) it still carries a nuance of them doing something (that makes it seem to us they are taking us lightly); and (b) it needs the passive and 〜ている form for it. As illustrated above, it does not express a state in its plain form.

He we see it is helpful to take a look at the differences in how stative and dynamic verbs are used.

## Aspect-wise, classification by 金田一春彦

In (some) analyses of English stative verbs, stative verbs do not take the continous aspect (ｘJohn is knowing the answer.)

Paralleling this distinction based upon aspect, there is a classification by 金田一春彦【きんだいちはるひこ】 from his article 国語動詞の一分類 (1950) in [the journal 言語研究第15号](https://www.jstage.jst.go.jp/browse/gengo1939/1950/15/_contents) ([link to pdf](https://www.jstage.jst.go.jp/article/gengo1939/1950/15/1950_48/_pdf)), which is explained for example here: [金田一の日本語動詞分類 1](http://amigo.hum.fukuoka-u.ac.jp/koga/index.php?blog/2009_11_27) and
[金田一の日本語動詞分類 2](http://amigo.hum.fukuoka-u.ac.jp/koga/index.php?blog/2010_04_05). Note that dynamic (動作動詞) verbs include punctual and durative verbs.

- durative (継続): 〜ている is used for a current action or completed action: 遊んでいる, ｘ子供は今公園で遊ぶ
- punctual (瞬間): 〜ている can only mean that the action is completed: (もう・すでに)死んでいる
- static/stative (状態): continous form 〜ている often not possible, plain form is used for a current action: 猫がいる, ｘ居ている
- 4th type (第四種): current action expressed by 〜ている, attributive form uses 〜た without expressing a past sense: 話はありふれている, ありふれた話 (this does not imply everybody already forgot about it)

Note that the plain form of durative verbs is used as well, of course. Try to compare a present situation, however, when the action/state is taking place presently.

> - 子供は今公園にいる
> - 子供は今公園で遊んでいる

Instantaneous:

> - 俺さまをなめてんのか？ → This means that he underestimates (=currently is underestimating) the speaker, not that he's done with it. → not instantaneous verb
> - (もう・すでに)なめている → This could be `is already underestimating`, but not a finished action such as もう死んでいる. → not instantaneous verb

Stative:

> - (お前は)(今)俺をなめる。 → This would not be used by somebody currently facing another person. → not stative verb
> - 俺をなめている。 → The *-te-iru* form is possible. → probably not stative verb

4th type:

> - あんたをなめた俺 → At most this would refer to the past. → not of 4th type

[Another test involves](https://books.google.de/books?id=l-C4H2sBJlEC&pg=PA60) testing whether we add the auxilaries -はじめる, expressing the start of an action. In 金田一春彦's article we find

> 「終る」という語と「始める」という語は継続動詞のみにつく。

Compare dynamic/stative verbs:

> - 話はじめるの
> - 飴を舐めはじめる
> - ｘ(運転)ができはじめる
> - ｘ値しはじめる

How about 舐める is the sense of `underestimate`? Usages are rare and need some context, but we can find some:

> **敵をなめはじめていた搭乗員たち**も、本気で取り組まざるをえなかつた。
>
> 田中光二, シドニー攻略, ISBN-13:9784059006077

or

> 最近**運転をなめはじめていた気がする**から、初心を思い出せました。

or

> まさかの鬼畜ステージ登場!回復ばかりのゆとり使用かと思いきや…。凶悪配置地獄、スノボー面が姿を現しました。正直、**このゲームを舐めはじめていたところです**。怖い怖い。

In English, you can use the plain form as in `I think that guy there underestimates me.` and consider it a stative verb in this case. But in Japanese that becomes 俺をなめている.

## Summary

Therefore I'd classify なめる as a dynamic verb. But perhaps its usage with different forms such as 〜ている is a remnant of its original meaning, and meaning-wise it is now often closer to a state.

As an exception, it could be regarded as being of `4th type` in なめたことを言う or なめた真似をする.

Comment: Well, this is my take. Perhaps somebody has got more insights on http://linguistics.stackexchange.com ?

Comment: Interesting, but I have a question regarding "俺は(今)あんたをなめる。 → This does not work by itself. → not stative verb." Why can't it work by itself? 見なす certainly does, as shown in my example sentence, but I can't find a Japanese dictionary that classifies it as stative.

Comment: I don't think なめている is a ongoing action. あんたをなめる is fine to my ears. Besides, I think there are very few verbs that cannot take ている form, perhaps only ある and いる. Even potential verbs are often used with ている, e.g. パンツが見えてるぞ。

Comment: @Joe Yes, most verbs can be used in the plain form. But think about a situation currently taking place: Would somebody say お前、俺をなめてるだろう or お前、俺をなめるだろう ? With stative verbs, it sounds fine if yousay 今いる？ or　水、要る？ or 賞賛に値する or それ、出来る？ or 走れる？ (not 走れている？)

Comment: See also here https://books.google.de/books?id=l-C4H2sBJlEC&pg=PA69 (`状態動詞:テイル形がない` and see at the top of 69 as well) We need to be careful whether this is  an argument about the definition of `stative verb`. There are more stative verbs than いる and ある, but the definition/categorization by 金田一 might be more narrow than what you might have in mind.

Comment: See also the edit.

Comment: That doesn't answer my previous comment on why 見なす, something classified as dynamic in Japanese dictionaries, acts stative when used in its dictionary form. Even tests like adding はじめる don't do anything to show if a verb is stative. For example, 敵だと思い始めた is plausible and means "began to think of him as an enemy" and yet 思う would still be stative, and a sentence like 敵だと見なし始めた would work similarly. In fact, using the もう test I suggested earlier, I feel that もう彼を舐めるな is best represented with "don't underestimate him anymore" and "underestimate" being a stative verb.

Comment: @Joe 工藤(1995) classifies 思う as 内的状態動詞. 吉永(1977) and 金田一(1950) classify those verbs as 継続動詞 (進行解釈; 憎む、悩む、焦る、苦しむ、悲しむ etc.) and 瞬間動詞 (結果解釈; 諦める、驚く、喜ぶ、呆れる、飽きる etc.) and both 瞬間動詞 and 継続動詞 are 動作動詞. So no, based upon the classification I'm referring to 思う is not considered a 状態動詞. As for 見なす, 見なしている is possible, but not as in 見なしつつある or 見なしている最中, so I'd say under 金田一 it would be a punctual verb (瞬間動詞), which are used in the plain form to express a current action.

Comment: So basically we're back at the beginning that it depends upon how we define it exactly and for what purpose (eg. 金田一 was concerned with aspects and 〜ている). I think simply saying "a verb expressing a state" might be too vague to be applied to unclear or edge cases. If you say もう彼を舐めるな feels more like "Don't underestimate(stative) him anymore." I might say I feel it's like "What you shouldn't be doing, is not taking him seriously(dynamic) any longer.". But perhaps it's worth to look at 工藤真由美's classification: 状態動詞, 主体動作動詞, 主体変化動詞, 主体動作・客体変化動詞, 可能動詞, 存在動詞

Comment: Actually, "take" in "not taking him seriously(dynamic) any longer" could be considered stative if we use merriam-webster's definition of "take" in 13b(3) of "to accept or regard with the mind in a specified way <took the news hard> <you take yourself too seriously" >http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/take. The trouble with 思う is that it can be both stative and dynamic and anyone classifying these verbs needs to take special care with these verbs.