# ending a sentence with て, is ておく implied?

Tags: て-form

> 部屋から出て行った。わめきたてるテレビをそのままに**して**。

I interpret this as

> [He] left the room, leaving the television blaring.

Firstly (though not required for an accepted answer), わめきたてる is confusing. Why not わめきたてている?

More importantly, how can we end this sentence in して? Why not しておいた。?

Is it implied, since we use そのままに?

Answer (score 1):

This is a case of 'right-dislocation', a constituent of the original sentence has been moved to the right periphery:

わめきたてるテレビをそのままにして部屋から出て行った ➞ 部屋から出て行った、わめきたてるテレビをそのままにして

This is largely a strategy adopted in the spoken language, and the effect of putting material at the beginning of a sentence is to add emphasis.

When a plain verb is adnominalized, the ～る form is sufficient to convey the meaning of continuity for a verb like わめく, and it may be that ～ている in that position emphasizes the state, rather than the continuous nature of the blaring of the television.

The interpretation of ～ている in an adnominalized sentence depends on how the verb is classified. Starting with the great Japanese linguist 金田一晴彦 in 1950, it has been recognized that verbs can be divided into classes, like 'stative' 状態動詞, 'durative', 継続動詞, 'punctual' 瞬間動詞, 'durative-stative' 状態発達動詞, and this affects the interpretation of various verb forms.

For example, 太る is a durative-stative verb, so 太っている人 and 太った人 are equivalent in meaning. 読む is 'durative' so 読んでいない can mean 'I no longer read' or 'I have not read yet', but the ～ていない form of 結婚する, a 'punctual' verb, 結婚していない, can only mean 'I am not married yet', not 'I am no longer married'.

Comment: P.S. しておいて instead of して would not be wrong, but it would emphasize the deliberateness of the act of leaving the television blaring. Perhaps the writer wasn't interested in that hence chose して.

Comment: Several things are difficult to follow in your answer, particularly for someone coming here for help with Japanese who is not a linguist.  What do you mean by *adnominalized*?  How does that related to the question?  Also, you nicely point out four different classes:  stative, durative, punctual, durative-stative.  But you don't explain what they mean.  For someone just interested in learning Japanese and not linguistic categories, while this information could be of interest, it is confusing for the nonspecialist.

Comment: In リンゴを食べる人, 'a man eating an apple', the sentence リンゴを食べる is said to be adnominalized to 人. In わきたてるテレビ we have a sentence わきたてる, adnominalized to テレビ. There are no hard-and-fast rules for determining the class of a verb. Most Japanese verbs are of the type I called 'durative', like 読む, 書く, 走る, 泳ぐ. They describe on-going actions. 'Punctual' verbs, as the name suggests, describe an instantaneous action: 気づく, 死ぬ, and 開く. See the comments and answers to [Is 舐める a stative verb?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/23911/is-%E8%88%90%E3%81%AA%E3%82%81%E3%82%8B-a-stative-verb).

Comment: Why say "adnominalized" and not just call リンゴを食べる a relative clause?

Comment: *Punctual* in normal English suggests "on time".  All I'm saying is that, if you're going to use fancy words, at least explain (within the body of your answer) for others who might not understand the jargon what the technical jargon means.  I definitely didn't understand adnominalized (sounds like a barbarism to me when there's a more obvious and sensible choice of "relative clause", but that's merely my opinion).  I myself actually do understand durative/stative etc.  But, a first year Japanese student, they probably don't understand these words or how they're being used.

Comment: In a nutshell, I think you put together a great answer.  But you're talking at a level beyond what I think is reasonable for the average person dropping by with questions about learning Japanese.  If you want to use the technical jargon, then explain it; don't assume that it's as obvious to everyone else as you believe it is for yourself.  I'd like to upvote your answer, but I can't right now because it's too laden with technical jargon with no explanation of what that jargon actually means.

Comment: I am quite happy to explain technical language if asked, and more often than not such technical language describes phenomena the learner has already encountered but which has never been explained properly or systematically. Especially for an English speaker learning Japanese, some linguistic knowledge is necessary to de-mystify the language. It is quite clear though, that there are those for whom mechanical procedures for analyzing language are anathema.

Comment: A quick search on stackexchange shows that I am guilty of being the first to use the term 'adnominalized', yet terms like, 'stative', 'punctual', 'relative clause', 'aspect', even 'scrambling' and 'head-internal relative clause', can be found in posts going back many years.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/149832/discussion-between-a-ellett-and-n-hunt).